# How can I stop debt collection agencies contacting me about an ex-partner who moved away 10 years ago?

Tags: united-kingdom, debt-collection

I divorced about 10 years ago and transferred my mortgage out of my partner's name. However it appears as if my ex has been taking out more loans and not paying them back and every month or so a different collection agency will get in touch. This is causing emotional distress to the remaining family.

Is there a way to stop debt collection agencies from approaching this address and telephone number? Is there something I should do to ensure he is not able to take out loans with this address or are the agencies just digging through his address history?

I'm in the UK.

**Clarification:** This isn't repeated calls from a few debt collection agencies, but different companies approaching about different loans each time. By and large, they are going away once told they are no longer at this address. I'm wondering more if there's something to be done to prevent them even approaching this address in the first place.

(asking this on behalf of someone else, clarifications may take a while).

Comment: Most likely the collection agencies are just grasping at straws trying to find him. If you were in the US, I'd have no problem writing an answer that basically says, "You're fine. Tell them to stop calling, ignore the noise." I hope a UK-specific response will say the same thing.

Comment: [CIFAS Identity Protection](https://www.cifas.org.uk/pr_for_individuals) might or might not be useful - it's not clear to me from [their FAQ](https://www.cifas.org.uk/pr_faqs) whether a matching *address* alone will trigger in their system. You could give them a call.

Comment: Based on first hand experience, the trouble with locating a "troubled debtor" (regardless of country) is that usually the individual tends to more more than average, might have more than one phone number, etc. If they're not paying the bank, they probably aren't paying their rent on time, the cell phone bill etc. Agencies spend HUNDREDS OF THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS just trying to get 'troubled debtors' on the phone.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who previously worked in Consumer Debt Collection: In the US at least, the typical practice is that once you receive the first contact, I would send, (fax, email, post, etc. ) a "Cease and Desist" Letter. You can even google a standard version of this.

Basically the letter is a written request to cease communications with you by phone, email, post, etc. I would even document the numbers and addresses you wish to not receive communication at.

Most financial institutions wish to avoid litigation, which basically just increases their costs.

Sometimes a short paragraph explaining that you are no longer financially or socially connected with or communicate with your ex.

Also, most (keyword most) debt collectors are reasonable people. If you get them on the phone, it might do well to explain your situation.

I wish this wasn't such a common occurrence. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful advice - unfortunately the situation is lots of different agencies (and banks, etc.) getting in touch about different loans. I was wondering about a blanket approach that all agencies could reference to see that someone wasn't living here. I've clarified the question but given you an upvote as it might help stop agencies coming back more than once.

Comment: Unfortunately, they all use different tactics, methods and resources. A good form letter/generic is helpful. I do understand the situation, I wish there was a better way. If you find one, market it!